# Button Frame in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have only one button in the UIBarButtonItem with an image. I would like to place it in the middle of the screen but am unable to adjust the frame. Please see the code and any leads would be useful.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;

[super viewDidLoad];



UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Email_Button.png"]; 
UIButton *emailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
emailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);
    [emailButton setImage:emailImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];



UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:emailButton];
//[aBarButtonItem setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 30)];

[emailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendEmail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:aBarButtonItem, nil];
[[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden: NO animated:YES];
[self setToolbarItems:arr animated:YES]; 
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the one button in the middle, you should probably use two Flexible Space Bar Button Items, put one on each side of your UIBarButtonItem, that should have the effect you desire...

create one like so

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]`
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"]) {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
    }
}
```